# SQL how to count how many months have passed since certain status

Tags: sql, oracle, status, lag

I have a table with project, period and status with their periodic values. My goal is to show how many months have passed since certain project was last in 'Approved status' (or show what period this status was changed) in the period_leaving_approved_status column. for example, for periods 201005 to 201008 - i would need to show '201005' values, but for periods 201011-201012 - '201011' values. I managed to mark the line where status changes, but i don't know how to apply the condition for the following rows. My example query :

```
with subq as (
select 123 as project,  201002 as period,   'Approved' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201003 as period,   'Approved' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201004 as period,   'Approved' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201005 as period,   'Pending Close' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201006 as period,   'Pending Close' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201007 as period,   'Closed' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201008 as period,   'Closed' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201009 as period,   'Approved' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201010 as period,   'Approved' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201011 as period,   'Closed' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201012 as period,   'Closed' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201101 as period,   'Approved' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201102 as period,   'Approved' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201112 as period,   'Approved' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201301 as period,   'Pending Close' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201302 as period,   'Closed' as status from dual
union all
select 123 as project,  201203 as period,   'Closed' as status from dual
)

select project, 
      period, 
      status,
      case when lag(status, 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY period)='Approved' 
      AND lag(status, 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY period) NOT IN(status) then period end as period_leaving_approved_status
      from subq
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this using aggregation:

```
select project,
       max(case when status = 'Approved' then period end) as ApprovedPeriod
from subq;
```

If you want the time span then something like this:

```
select project,
       months_between(max(case when status = 'Approved' then period end),
                      sysdate) as monthsSinceApproved,
       max(case when status = 'Approved' then period end) as ApprovedPeriod
from subq
group by project;
```

EDIT:

If you want this information cumulatively on all rows, then use window functions:

```
select s.*,
       max(case when status = 'Approved' then period end) over
           (partition b project order by period) as LastApprovedPeriod
from subq s;
```

Comment: You see, this will always take only the LAST approved period. But  for example for period=201005 the value should be 201004 not  201112

Comment: @user3014914 . . . The question states:  "since certain project was last in 'Approved status' ".

Comment: @Gordon Maybe OP wants to add that information per row relative to the period?